# HDD partition disappeared

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have an SSD that has Ubuntu installed, and a data HDD which used to be `sdb`. The hard drive has lots of data in it already. Now, I see `fdisk` doesn't show all partitions correctly and something has been changed. Below is the output from fdisk. First, the HDD is now shown as `sda`, but without partition (e.g. `sda1`). So I can't mount it.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B50CD632-617E-47EA-A984-B0A6096801E3

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     1050624 1819488255 1818437632 867.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  1819488256 1953523711  134035456  63.9G Linux swap
```

When I check `/etc/fstab`, it shows

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=65266004-ca77-48bc-97ce-28baa4002799 /               ext4            errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=50B9-B0CF  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=ea9208b6-a4b1-4540-95ab-68fa7fe4d6bb none            swap    sw              0       0
```

What can I do to recover access to my HDD (`/dev/sda` above, but mysteriously it used to be `sdb1`)?

(Edit: below is the result from parted --list)

```
$ sudo parted --list

Model: ATA TOSHIBA HDWE140 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
1      0.00B  4001GB  4001GB  ext4


Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name         Flags
1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition boot, esp
2      538MB   932GB   931GB   ext4
3      932GB   1000GB  68.6GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: what happens if you type `sudo mkdir /mnt/4GB && sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/4GB` ?  Is all your data available now in `/mnt/4GB`?

Comment: it doesn't mount... and I get an error message: "mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist". As displayed above, the fdisk -l output does not show sda1 (but it shows sda).

Comment: what does `fsck -C -r /dev/sda` give you?

Comment: (sorry for the delay) fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda: clean, 866620/244195328 files, 189766239/976754646 blocks
/dev/sda: status 0, rss 4104, real 0.889664, user 0.804000, sys 0.004000

Comment: No bad superblock, so you're left with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and follow the [step-by-step guide](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: Don't thank me yet! If you've used that hard drive for something else in the meantime, your rate of cuccess will be low.